# Starting thread in multifile project

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm having issues with multithreading and multifile projects. Works fine when testing with a single file project but as I am trying to keep my headers separated from my implimentation, is there a way to make this work?

the error I am getting is:
error C3867: 'class1::Update': function call missing argument list; use '&class1::Update' to create a pointer to member

Sadly, the suggestion there doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Class1.H

```
class class1
{
public:
    class1();
    ~class1();


private:
    thread sThread;
    void Update();
};
```

Class1.cpp

```
int class1::Initialize()
{
    this->sThread = std::thread(Update);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the error is:

```
'class1::Update': function call missing argument list; use '&class1::Update' to create a pointer to member
```

So do that.  Once you do you will find that you then need to use `std::bind()` to attach an instance of the class to the member function.  That will look like:

```
thread(bind(&class1::Update, this))
```

Comment: I now have this->sThread = std::thread(bind(&class1::Update, this)); and I get this error:

Error 491 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall class1::Update(void)" (?Update@class1@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall class1::Initialize(void)" (?Initialize@class1@@QAEHXZ)

Comment: ignore that. Accidentally had the implimentation of Update commented out.